# Deleting items in a Dynamodb table with duplicate values

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with the following structure:

```
{  
  accountId: string,//PRIMARY KEY 
  userId: string,//SORT KEY
  email: string,
  dateCreated: number // timestamp
}
```

I want to perform an action that deletes all items with duplicate emails from the table except for the one with the oldest dateCreated attribute.

Is this operation possible in DynamoDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you need both **partition and sort keys** to delete an item from DynamoDB. Unless, you know the `accountId` and `userId`, you can't perform the delete item operation.

On the above use case, neither `email` nor `dateCreated` attribute is part of the key attribute.

Also, sort functionality is available for the sort key attribute only.

**Approach 1:-**

Preferred one if it is a **one time activity**

1. Get the data and identify the old values based on `dateCreated` at client side
2. Delete the data on DynamoDB based on `accountId` and `userId`

**Approach 2:-**

Preferred one if it is **required frequently**

3. Create a GSI with hash key as `email` and sort key as `dateCreated`
4. Assuming you know the email id that you wanted to query against and identify whether it has duplicates, you can use **Query API** with index name, email id value and `ScanIndexForward` value as false (i.e. descending order)

The result set will have email id with latest record at the top. You can ignore the top record and run the **Delete API** with `accountId` and `userId` for the rest of the items.

**Approach 3:-**

Preferred approach if the data can be manageable at flat file and run some program to find the duplicates

1. You can export the data to S3 bucket using AWS Data Pipeline
2. Run some program to read the file to find the duplicates and execute the DynamoDB delete query to delete the item

**Approach 4:-**

Preferred approach if the data is large

1. You can export the data to AWS EMR using AWS Data Pipeline
2. Run some queries to find the duplicates and execute the DynamoDB delete query to delete the item

**Note:-**

Please note that if you are expecting something like SQL with sub-queries to identify the latest updated record and delete the rest, it is **NOT** possible on DynamoDB

[Export data to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html)

Comment: Kudos. That is a well-explained answer.